# How to share device State information from electron

Tags: azure-active-directory, electron, single-sign-on, desktop-application

We have developed a desktop application using electron and angular, bundled using electron-builder.
The problem we are facing is regarding SSO, we have achieved SSO by attaching 'debugger' on 'webContents' of a 'BrowserWindow', it's working for the normal scenarios though there is a scenario in which it is not working properly.

here we have implemented device based conditional access policy, which blocks application (either browser or desktop-based app) access triggered from unmanaged device and grant full access only to managed device. Here conditional access policy identifies the device state shared by the application only.

Due to that, we are shown below image.

[image]

after that we tried to check same for the web browser, but it works properly for the browsers. Here the problem could be.

- **Application settings:**
  The application may not be configured to share device state when a user logs in. In this case, check the application settings to ensure that the option is enabled.
- **Application bugs**
  There could be bugs or issues in the application that prevent it from sharing device state while a user logs in.

we were able to find that by setting "**AllowSingleSignOnUsingOSPrimaryAccount**" to "**True**" will work properly. [image]

Is there any way we can set flag "AllowSingleSignOnUsingOSPrimaryAccount" in Electron, or do any other support in Electron for such thing, or have any alternative to solve the mentioned problem?